# Issue Installing TensorFlow or PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to Install TensorFlow or PyTorch. I tried doing in a normal project and also a virtual project. These are the errors I get and I tried many different versions and reading documentation.

```bash
pip install torch
pip3 install torch --no-cache-dir
pip install "tensorflow<2.11"
pip install tensorflow==2.0
pip install tensorflow --user
pip3 install tensorflow
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.10.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whlA
py -m pip install torch
py -m pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

and many other different tries

Python Version:

```
Python 3.12.0
pip 23.3.1
```

I also tried to use Conda

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch
> (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==2.10.0 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.10.0
>
> ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.10.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a
> supported wheel on this platform.
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not
> visible in this virtualenv.
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> torch==2.0.1 (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.0.1
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow[and-cuda] (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow[and-cuda]
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.

and many other errors as I entered the install commands for pytorch or sensorflow

I need to have 1 of these libraries to use transformers in huggingface.
I tried to install this in a Virtual Environment and out of one.

Thank you

Comment: python not python3

Comment: I tried both. python and python3, Im currently just trying to Install the packages so I can use them. it should be simple! but i'm not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: py -m pip install tensorflow --upgrade It is Released: Sep 26, 2023

Comment: Same errors as above with that command I just tried
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: One last question. Did you update Pytorch?

Comment: its doing something! I just exited my virtual environment tensorflow installing or trying atm and no I had the same issues with pytorch

Comment: Are you using raspberry pi?

Comment: so it said it installed. but right at the beginning of my script it read this:
None of PyTorch, TensorFlow >= 2.0, or Flax have been found. Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used.

then in my script when i went to execute my transform code :
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.

Comment: Please tell us something about your hardware (CPU, GPU)+OS.

Comment: i7 Intel with Windows 10, I was planning on only using CPU version since its small what im using it for. I trouble shoorted earlier with toyota supra and we couldnt figure it out